# "kubectl describe pod" does not report proper url of liveness probe

Tags: http, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Below is the report for liveness & readiness after running `kubectl -n mynamespace describe pod pod1`:

```
Liveness:   http-get http://:8080/a/b/c/.well-known/heartbeat delay=3s timeout=3s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:  http-get http://:8080/a/b/c/.well-known/heartbeat delay=3s timeout=3s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
```

---

1. Is this the valid(working) url? `http://:80/`
2. What does `#success=1 #failure=3` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are completely right:

- http://:8080 indicates that it will try an http-get in port 8080 inside your pod
- #success=1 indicates a success threshold of 1 (the default), so the first time it gets an answer it will mark the pod as live or ready
- #failure=3 indicates a failure threshold of 3 (the default again), so the third time the call fails will mark it unready or try to restart it.

See the official docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes

You may try to execute this command to see how the probes are configured:

```bash
kubectl -n mynamespace get pod pod1 -o yaml
```

Comment: why is there a "# in front of success and failure? The other values do not carry this prefix? Initially, I thought this was used to indicate that default values are being used but when I change the failure to say 5, I still have a # in front of failure so unsure if the # prefix has a specific meaning.