# Do the # in front of success and failure in Kubectl pod Describe (Kubernetes) mean something?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check, readinessprobe, livenessprobe, startup-probe

Does the # in front of success and failure in a Kubectl describe (refer picture) meant to represent something?

All of the elements in each of those probes represent a config element for the probe but success and failure are prefixed with a #. I initially thought maybe it is a default value (which was not specified by the user but noticed that this is not the case as the picture shows different values for all the failure config for the various probes.

Am I reading too much into the # or is it intentionally placed there for a reason?

It does not make a difference to the functionality or affect us in any form or shape. Just Curious as it catches the eye!

Noticed a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69419096/kubectl-describe-pod-does-not-report-proper-url-of-liveness-probe/69419270#comment128849330_69419270) but it doesn't focus on the "#".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be just be embedded into the print statement:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b1e130fe83156783153538b6d79821c2fdaa85bb/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/describe/describe.go#L1956

Here is the original PR:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/21341

Looked into messaging the original author, but he disables DMs on his social media.

Answer (score 1):

Those are default values only."#" is just an indication of default values for "successThreshold" and "failureThreshold". Though the attribute names which we define in definition and what we see when we describe the resource are bit different.  For Ex: we have to mention failureThreshold attribute in the definition but when you describe it will come as failure.  The default value for failureThreshold is 3 for readiness probe.  same for initialDelaySeconds it will just display as "delay".  The attributes and default values are in [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) documentation